# How do I add a button or link to the product list page in the admin area?

Tags: nopcommerce

How do I add a new button / link to the product list page in the admin area? I have a plugin that will generate an xml file from the products in the nop db and would like to add a button to this page for the admin user to use. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Please note that I am aware that I can change the `Views\Product\List.cshtml` to add the extra html, but as I am writing a plugin, I cannot change the source code of the main application. I have in the past added new tabs inside the "Edit Product" page by implementing `IConsumer<AdminTabStripCreated>`, and I was hoping there might be something similar I could do here. If it is not possible to inject any html to the product list, then I am open to suggestions for the next best thing.. maybe a link on the nav menu or something?

**EDIT 2**

I have just tried implementing `IAdminMenuPlugin` as per this Nop thread:
http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/21123/how-can-i-add-admin-menu-items-from-plugin.aspx

Doesn't seem to work though. I even tried uninstalling and re-installing the plugin.

From `RouteProvider`:

```
routes.MapRoute("Plugin.Widgets.ZapXml.Generate",
                 "Plugins/ZapXml/Generate",
                 new { controller = "ZapXml", action = "Generate" },
                 new[] { "Nop.Plugin.Widgets.ZapXml.Controllers" }
            );
```

From plugin class (which inherits `BasePlugin` and `IAdminMenuPlugin`):

```
public void BuildMenuItem(Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.MenuItemBuilder menuItemBuilder)
        {
            menuItemBuilder.Text("Generate Zap XML File");
            menuItemBuilder.Url("Plugins/ZapXml/Generate");
            menuItemBuilder.Route("Plugin.Widgets.ZapXml.Generate");
        }
```

I put a breakpoint in `BuildMenuItem` but it is never hit. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was not able to find any way to add a button or link to the Product List page like I wanted. Instead, I discovered `IAdminMenuPlugin` and implemented that. I had some issues with it at first where it would not work even after rebuilding the plugin, uninstalling and re-installing it. However, after clearing the cache, restarting the site, etc. then it started working. So it's not ideal, but it will suffice.